# Reorder radio buttons that are in a table based on the amount least to greatest using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working within a template so I cannot directly edit the HTML. The radio button items are automatically sorted from greatest to least but I would like them to appear from least to greatest.

```
<tbody>

<tr class="CTsubtitle">
<td width="1%"><font class="CTtablein">&nbsp;</font></td>
<td><font class="CTtablein">Level</font></td>
</tr>

<tr class="CTodd"><td nowrap=""><font class="CT">&nbsp;
<input type="radio" id="Radio1" onclick="SetAmount(form, 500);" value="749500" name="PledgeLevelID">
&nbsp;</font></td>
<td><font class="CT">$500.00 (becomes $1000.00 when matched)&nbsp;</font><br></td>
</tr>

<tr class="CTeven"><td nowrap=""><font class="CT">&nbsp;
<input type="radio" id="Radio1" onclick="SetAmount(form, 250);" value="749511" name="PledgeLevelID">&nbsp;</font></td>
<td><font class="CT">$250.00  (becomes $500 when matched)&nbsp;</font><br></td>
</tr>

<tr class="CTodd"><td nowrap=""><font class="CT">&nbsp;
<input type="radio" id="Radio1" onclick="SetAmount(form, 100);" value="749499" name="PledgeLevelID">&nbsp;</font></td>
<td><font class="CT">$100.00 (becomes $200 when matched)&nbsp;</font><br></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

I have been working with this example in fiddler: 
http://jsfiddle.net/HELUq/1/

Answer (score 1):

Updated to your requirements:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var compare = function (a,b){
      var a_val = $(a).find("font").text().replace(/[\n\r]/g, "");
        a_val = parseInt(a_val.substring(a_val.indexOf("$")+1));
      var b_val = $(b).find("font").text().replace(/[\n\r]/g, "");
        b_val = parseInt(b_val.substring(b_val.indexOf("$")+1));
      if (a_val>b_val){
        return 1;
      }
      if (a_val<b_val){
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    };

    $("table tr").not(".CTsubtitle").sort(compare).appendTo("table");
});
```

Take a look at this - http://jsfiddle.net/maximua/6nQKD/3/

Comment: Thanks Max, trying to work with this but it may be too much, I don't need to have a sort option, I need the items reordered. I am working with a template and cannot simply move the items around but I would like the options to appear on load from the least amount to the greatest amount. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VWJYh/).

This will sort ascending by the myAttribute element attribute.

```
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).attr('myAttribute') - $(b).attr('myAttribute');
});
```

Comment: It looks like you would need either a row ID or an attribute to identify the row in this case, but I don't have this.